# contents of .idea/workspace.xml file file triggers safety problems

Tags: android, intellij-idea, workspace

I see "" in this file. I wonder what this file is for and where I can find the explanation of each parts & structure of this file.

Comment: This file stores user specific settings for the project, like run/debug configurations, window layout, etc. There is no full description available since it's not designed to be modified by hand. It should be excluded from the version control, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839.